# Problem With Variables And Objects

Tags: javascript, variables, object, null

I have 3 `TextFields`, called `txtUSD`, `txtEUR`, `txtAUS`. And a `PopupList` with the same values, minus the `txt` part, but I need to form the names of the `TextFields`  to use based on the selection that the user made. So I've done this:

```
function btConvert_Click(event)
{
    var amount = document.getElementById("txtAmount").value;
    var rates = document.getElementById("lstConvertTo").value;
    var from = "txt" + document.getElementById("lstFrom").options[document.getElementById('lstFrom').selectedIndex].text;
    var to = "txt" + document.getElementById("lstConvertTo").options[document.getElementById("lstConvertTo").selectedIndex].text;
    var curr_from = document.getElementById(from).value;
    var curr_to = document.getElementById(to).value;

    if(curr_from > curr_to)
    {
        amount * rates;
    } else {
        amount / rates;
    }
    alert(result);
}
```

But every time I try it I get this error:

> mobile/main.js line 215: Result of expression 'document.getElementById(from)' [null] is not an object.

How should I make it?

Comment: do you have element with id `from` and `to` ?

Comment: O, boy pure javascript is so painful :O

Comment: They are all at `value` and the values of `from` and `to` should be the combination of `txt` + The selected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error you're getting, it looks like there's a bug when generating the `from` variable.

You should consider storing `document.getElementById('lstFrom')` into it's own var, for brevity.